# how to add units?

Tags: jquery

How to add height , width unit to image using jquery , like `pixel, %` ect

```
var img = new Image();   
 // Create image 
$(img).load(function(){                  
    imgdiv.append(this); 
}).error(function () {   
    $('#adsloder').remove(); 
}).attr({  
    id: val.ADV_ID,   
    src: val.ADV_SRC, 
    title: val.ADV_TITLE, 
    alt: val.ADV_ALT 
}).height(100).width(100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set both in one declaration:

```
$(img).css({
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%'
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I quote the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2):

> `.height( value )`
>   `value` An **integer** representing the **number of pixels**, or an integer with an **optional unit** of measure appended (**as a string**).

Answer (score 0):

You can set that through CSS:

```
$(img).css('height', '100%');
```

Comment: what is the way to add height width both ?